# SQL Server datetime intput in insert string cause issue in Spanish OS

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

We are using MS SQL Server to develop application whereas we have datetime columns in multiple tables ..To avoid datetime culture problem, we always convert datetime to invariant culture string to maintain unique format..

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection("connectionString");
        DateTime currentDate=DateTime.Now;

        string insertCommand= "Insert INTO Table [MyTable] (MyDateColumn)
     Values ("+currentDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)+")" 

  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, sqlConnection);

  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So here, for whatever the UI and dateTime culture, the currentDate simply changed into neutral format like '02/12/2014 14:34:47'. It is working well in our work and test environment.

But today one of our spanish customer(spanish) raised the datetime conversion issue '**Converting data type varchar to datetime produced a value out of range. The statement has been terminated**'

So, here my questions are

```
i) Whether we need to give SQL datetime string input depends on SQL Server culture ?
ii) If so, what is the best generic way to give datetime inputs in SQL server?
```

Comment: over all how are you changing the culture of application. ?Are you using c# to do so ?

Comment: how you execute `insertCommand`, using `SqlCommand` object? try to use parametrized query, and pass DateTime object instead of string as parameter. That will save you from sql injection and complexity of managing DateTime format in various culture.

Comment: @kombsh,then there must 2 line in your code to so.
I suggest you to comment second line.also refer msdn and read the purpose of those 2 lines.This is what I remember now.

Comment: guys , now you can see that two lines (: -edited question

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized query, then you can simply pass `DateTime` object instead of string as parameter. That will save you from sql injection and complexity of converting `DateTime` object to a valid date time string according to sql server specific culture that currently active.

```
......
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var insertCommand = "Insert INTO Table [MyTable] (MyDateColumn)Values (@currentDate)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertCommand , sqlConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentDate", currentDate);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
......
```